# What tricks can I use to make the (x-1) factor appear when checking the limit of P(x) by definition of limit of function

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

The question asked us to prove the limit of P(x) with x->1 is -1 by checking the definition of limit of function. I got stuck when trying to get the (x-1) factor when simplifying |p(x) - (-1)|.

Comment: What is the relation between a) "checking the deifnition of limit" and b) "trying to get the $(x-1)$ factor" ?

Comment: Since we are required to use the definition of limit of function to show the limit is 1, which means we are required to show something like " for any epsilon > 0, there exists a K such that |x - 1| < epsilon".

Answer (score 0):

Bound $\cos(\pi x)$ above and below with its one-term and two-term Taylor approximations expanded around $x = 1$: $0$ and $-(\pi (x-1))$.